# Generating a random integer excluding certain values

Tags: python, random

I have made simple code to generate a random 7 digit number between  1111111 and 9999997

```
import random

key = random.randint(1111111, 9999997)

print(key)
```

I need this number to not contain 0, 8 or 9 as the last digit. It also needs to be divisible by 21. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried to solve your actual goal? Do you know how to *test* if a number does "not contain 0, 8 or 9 as the last digit" and is "divisible by 21"?

Comment: Generate a random number within the smaller range, then multiply with 21 and check constraints are satisfied. If not, repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loop until your number fits your conditions, then break:

```
import random

while True:     
    key = random.randint(1111111, 9999997)
    if key % 21 == 0 and str(key)[-1] not in "089":
        break

print(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
valid_numbers = [i for i in range(1111111, 9999997+1) if (i % 10 != 0) and (i % 10 != 8) and (i % 10 != 9) and (i % 21 == 0)]
key = random.choice(valid_numbers)
```

The first line uses a list comprehension with a conditional `if` to generate a list of all the numbers that fit your criteria.  Note that the second parameter to `range` needs to be one greater than the last number you need.  To get the last digit of a number you can use the modulo operator `%` with 10: `i % 10` gives the last decimal digit of `i`.  Likewise `i % 21 == 0` tells you if the number divides evenly by 21.

Once you have that list, it's just a matter of picking a number from the list with [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice).

Comment: please explain your code and how it solves the problem in the question

Comment: @OphirCarmi simple code with appropriate naming shouldn't need a lot of explanation.  The first line generates a list of acceptable numbers using the criteria posted in the question.  The second line chooses one of those numbers randomly.

Comment: An answer requiring "only a simple line of code", usually needs an explanation, for a beginner, or to have even been asked. Also, while easy for us to slog through, the "simple" line actually is comprised of compound statements, & cannot even be read without scrolling. It's almost always easier to read English than interpret/translate code to English. Finally, it sets a poor example from a very high rep user to be so cavalier & antagonistic. A simple sentence is friendly, & aids understanding. If the Q is so simple, does it already have an existing answer on SO? Or best left as a Comment.

Comment: @SherylHohman No need to be that hard on the answerer. After all, he is the one who voluntarily handed out a correct, elegant solution, and also provided an explanation when specifically asked for it.  However, a minimal discussion of the approach taken is missing in my opinion. Calculating 18 million divs is not for free, even more so in phyton. On the other hand, this is a simple way to ensure the distribution is preserved. This kind of discussion of the pros and cons is what benefits an answer.

Comment: @L.Riemer thanks for the defense, but the commenters had a point.  I had hoped that the code would speak for itself, but that obviously wasn't the case.  I think SO guidelines specifically discourage code-only answers just for that reason.  I still haven't included a discussion of the tradeoffs of this approach vs. other approaches.